# isactive and activeclassname at once in navlink

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I tried to build a react router component which update redux state when component is active, but I also want to set another active Class name for each NavLink. Unfortunately isActive is in collision with activeClassName, and when I’m trying to use it both, only isActive prop works. Is there any way to use them both at once?

```
class NavBar extends Component{
render(){
    const {color} = this.props

    const someFunc = () =>{
        someFunction(xdxd)
    }
    const otherFunc = () =>{
        someFunction(abcd)
    }
    return (
    <nav id="menu" className=" d-flex flex-column position-fixed">
        <ul id="Nav"className="mb-0 d-flex flex-column list-group">
            <NavLink style={{color}}  isActive={someFunc} activeClassName="my-bg-gray" className="menu-li mt-auto mr-0 mb-0 ml-auto rounded-circle" id="about_button" exact to="/"
                >a</NavLink>
            <NavLink style={{color}}  isActive={someFunc} activeClassName="my-bg-gray" className="menu-li mt-auto mr-0 mb-0 ml-auto rounded-circle" id="projects_button" to="/projects"
                >b</NavLink>
            <NavLink style={{color}}  isActive={someFunc} activeClassName="my-bg-green"className="menu-li mt-auto mr-0 mb-0 ml-auto rounded-circle" id="abilities_button" to="/abilities" 
                >c</NavLink>
            <NavLink style={{color}}  isActive={otherFunc}  activeClassName="my-bg-green"className="menu-li mt-auto mr-0 mb-0 ml-auto rounded-circle" id="education_button" to="/education" 
                >d</NavLink>
            <NavLink style={{color}}  isActive={otherFunc}  activeClassName="bg-white" className="menu-li mt-auto mr-0 mb-0 ml-auto rounded-circle" id="sendmessage_button" to="/sendmessage" 
                >e</NavLink>
            <NavLink style={{color}}  isActive={otherFunc}  activeClassName="my-bg-green" className="menu-li mt-auto mr-0 mb-0 ml-auto rounded-circle" id="socials_button" to="/socials" 
                >f</NavLink>
        </ul>
    </nav>
);}}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { color: state.color };
  };

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{})(NavBar);
```

Comment: Can you share [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example that repros your issue or share the snippet of your code?

Comment: Care to share what `someFunc` or `otherFunc` actually do? Are these functions issuing side-effects like calling redux actions? Are they updating `color`? What is the `style={{ color }}` style doing? Is there a global CSS style sheet with a duplicate/conflicting identifier? [`isActive`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md#isactive-func) is simply a boolean to indicate if the route is active or not, and if so, applies the `activeClassName`.

Comment: color is a redux state. someFunc updates color.